# cordova keyboard showing in every form page automatically

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Am trying build a App using ionic frame work with angularJS which has lot of forms. when ever i open form page keyboard opens automatically. am using ionic keyboard. I have used

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
```

but no use.

please help me to stop keyboard opening automatically.

Comment: I have same problem, and here is my **template**:
    _<label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" ng-model="search.input" placeholder="Search" />
    </label>_
 **and in config.xml I used**
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same issue by adding the below attribute to the button or element that opens the form.

```
data-tap-disabled="true"
```

eg:

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true" ng-click="openForm()"> Click here to open form </div>
```

More documentation can be found on the below link

[**Link Here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when the click event was handled after the page trasitioned. See the GitHub issue I opened: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3649