# iOS Swift 2.2 WebView (Polymer) prevent Keyboard from opening

Tags: ios, webview, swift2, virtual-keyboard

My iOS Swift App loads an UIWebView with Polymer content.

If the Users taps into the WebView, the first time after loading the WebView, the Keyboard shows up.

It doesnt matter where the User Taps.

How can I prevent the Keyboard from opening in that case?

Comment: Does this sound relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996464/cordova-keyboard-showing-in-every-form-page-automatically

Comment: Unfortunately no.. this issue is about the keyboard opening when taping in a form with a cordova build